# Enabling In-browser elevated trust

Tags: silverlight, full-trust

I'm trying to get in-browser elevated trust to work and having an issue.  I've:

1. Purchased a certificate
2. Signed the xap with that certificate
3. Added AllowElevatedTrustAppsInBrowser=1 in the registry

Yet the app still doesn't think it is running in elevated trust.  Any ideas on what I might be missing?

Running off localhost, of course, works because it doesn't require any of the above.

Screenshots included below as proof.

[image]
[image: Certificate Store]

Comment: Did you set the AllowElevatedTrustAppsInBrowser registry for both the 32 and 64 bit registries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have your certificate from a trusted publisher.
You have signed the XAP.
You have installed the certificate on the client computers.

Have you configured the registry on the client as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9784200/silverlight-5-signing-xap-file)?

You can also configure the registry settings using [Group Policy](http://www.grouppolicy.biz/tag/allowelevatedtrustappsinbrowser/)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to put the AppManifest.xaml along with the .xap file. I got the same problem, and it solved by having the .xaml. This is an old post, but hope it will help some one having the same problem.